# Need double quote on string value

Tags: xslt-1.0

Is there any way in xslt 1.0 the "/" separated string convert to comma separated and enclosed with double quotes.

input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<process xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Application1/Project1/BPELProcess1">
   <input>input1/input2/input3/input4</input>
</process>
```

output:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<ns0:processResponse xmlns:plnk="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/plnktype" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Application1/Project1/BPELProcess1">
   <ns0:result>"input1","input2","input3","input4"</ns0:result>
</ns0:processResponse>
```

Comment: 1. Why would you want that? 2. What if the input contains double quotes?

Comment: I think it should it be split into multiple elements with `maxOccurs="unbounded"`. Does the schema not allow for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Application1/Project1/BPELProcess1">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/ns0:process">
    <ns0:processResponse xmlns:plnk="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/plnktype" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" >
        <ns0:result>
            <xsl:call-template name="convert">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="ns0:input"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </ns0:result>
    </ns0:processResponse>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="convert">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:if test="$string">
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($string, '/'), '/')" />
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="contains($string, '/')">
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:call-template name="convert">
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string, '/')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It could be simpler if your processor supports EXSLT str:tokenize or str:split extension function.

Notice that this does not escape existing quotation marks, like you would expect with a CSV.